# Negative adjusted R squared in svyglm

Tags: r, statistics, data-science, survey

I have a large, weighted and stratified dataset containing among other things co2 emissions per household. The variable `total_co2` equals the sum `elec_co2 + gas_co2 + oil_co2`. Before moving to more complex relationships I tried to construct a seemingly obvious model.

```
svy <- svydesign(id=~i_psu,
                 strata=~i_strata,
                 weights=~i_hhdenui_xw,
                 data=df1)

model <- svyglm(total_co2 ~ elec_co2, svy)
summ(model)
```

```
MODEL INFO:
Observations: 6826
Dependent Variable: total_co2
Type: Survey-weighted linear regression 

MODEL FIT:
R² = 0.31
Adj. R² = -1.74 

Standard errors: Robust
---------------------------------------------------
                       Est.    S.E.   t val.      p
----------------- --------- ------- -------- ------
(Intercept)         1962.48   83.68    23.45   0.00
elec_co2               1.27    0.05    23.98   0.00
---------------------------------------------------

Estimated dispersion parameter = 4390445
```

While the `R^2` indicates some explanatory power, the `Adj. R^2` is negative, which is usually interpreted as indicating the opposite. How is this possible in such a simple relationship? Where does the negative value come from and how should I interpret it?

Here is a simple plot of the data.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The negative values for adjusted R square are due to a bug in the `summ` function of `jtools`. Further information here: https://github.com/jacob-long/jtools/issues/112

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: the adjusted R-squared formula allows negative answers and if the chosen model fits worse than a horizontal line, then R-squared is negative.

Long answer:
This other comment goes much more in-depth into negative R-squared values:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/12991

This webpage goes in-depth into the adjusted R-squared formula:
https://www.statisticshowto.com/adjusted-r2/

I recommend trying other models or adding the elec_co2, gas_co2, and oil_co2 separately.

Comment: Hallo Sarah, thanks for the quick reply. Actually total_co2 is modelled as a sum that contains elec_co2: `df$total_co2 <- df$elec_co2 + df$gas_co2 + df$oil_co2`.

So there is a very simple linear relationship that should be easy to capture for svyglm. And indeed the R² indicates some explanatory power.

On the other hand, if one computes the formula for adjusted R-square **by hand**, one would arrive at `adj. R^2 = 0.31`. However, this formula is given for unweighted data. What I dont understand is how `surveyglm` incorporates the weights and arrives at a negative value.

Comment: In that case, since the dependent variable is only total_co2 then you can disregard the adjusted R-squared. My understanding of linear regression is the adjusted R-squared is only used when you have two or more dependent variables. If you run the model including both total_co2 and elec_co2 (or gas_co2 or oil_co2), does the adjusted R-squared value change?

Comment: I tried to look in the docs of svydesign to find why the adjusted R-squared would be negative and I was not finding an answer. So another option would be to try a different R package to calculate your linear regression model to check the R-squared and the adjusted R-squared values. I've had success using the lm() function, detailed [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/lm)

Comment: Hey Sarah, thanks again for sharing your experiences. Indeed the adj R^2 becomes positive if i add gas_co2. But in this case R^2 is already very close to 1. In general I observed that the adj. R^2 values that I get from using weighted linear regression with `surveyglm` are a lot lower than the values i get from standard `glm` without weights. 
I guess it has something to do with how weights are incorporated into the calculation of adj R^2 by `surveyglm`. For now i will use the values of adj R^2 not as an absolute indicator of model performance but only as a relative measure between two models